# Generate Sitemap XML

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, tom.net, dxa-1.7

Our Environment : SDL Tridion 2013 SP1
I'm new to Tridion. We are trying to generate sitemap.xml for the site using Tridion. We wrote TBB which generated the sitemap in XML format and its being generated correctly. Now how would I call this from my .NET application and render it to the View and display the generated XML format on the page. I tried calling the hard coded file name (sitemap.xml) in controller and getting the xml data in string format correctly, now I need to pass this string from controller to View to display the data in XML format. Please suggest:

1. the approach is correct to generate sitemap.xml and
2. how to pass the XML of string format to View, so that it display in xml format

Comment: You mentioned views and controllers, are you using DD4T or DXA, or is it a custom MVC app?

Comment: .Net DXA 1.7 application

Comment: DXA provides sitemap.xml OOTB. Why are you trying to generate it yourself?

Answer (score 2):

Since, you are using DXA, I will say the approach of generating the sitemap might not makes sense (unless there are other fine prints which we are not aware about).

The correct approach could be similar to the one mentioned here:
[Generate Sitemap XML File using default functions of DXA 1.5/1.7 in Web 8/8.5](https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/generate-sitemap-xml-file-using-default-functions-of-dxa-1-5-1-7-in-web-8-8-5-tridion)